how to extract a cell value from a dataframe?
I am trying to extract a cell value from a dataframe, then why I always get a series instead of a value.
For example:
df_test=pd.DataFrame({'Well':['test1','test2','test3'],'Region':['east','west','east']})
df_test

Well    Region
0   test1   east
1   test2   west
2   test3   eas

well='test2'
region_thiswell=df_test.loc[df_test['Well']==well,'Region']
region_thiswell
1    west
Name: Region, dtype: object

I am expecting variable of region_thiswell is equal to 'west' string only. Why I am getting a series?
Thanks

A potential issue with item/values/iloc is that it will yield an exception of there is no match. squeeze will return an empty Series:
df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test999', "Region"].item()
# ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test999', "Region"].values[0]
# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test999', "Region"].iloc[0]
# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test999', "Region"].squeeze()
# Series([], Name: Region, dtype: object)

One robust approach to get a scalar would be to use next+iter:
next(iter(df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test2', "Region"]), None)
# 'west'

next(iter(df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test999', "Region"]), None)
# None

In case of multiple matches you'll get the first one:
next(iter(df_test.loc[df_test["Well"].str.startswith('test'), "Region"]), None)
# 'east'

Alternatively, but more verbose and less efficient:
df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == 'test999', "Region"].reset_index().get(0)


Wow, that’s brilliant and secure! Great to know this approach from you, +1!

When you use df_test.loc[df_test['Well'] == well, 'Region'], it returns a series because the condition can match multiple rows, even if in this case it matches only one.
Possible solutions:
df_test.loc[df_test['Well']==well,'Region'].iloc[0]


df_test.loc[df_test['Well']==well,'Region'].values[0]


df_test.loc[df_test['Well']==well,'Region'].squeeze()


To deal with @mozway's comment that squeeze will return a series if there is no match, a possible solution is the following. In truth, we only need to check whether the series is empty:
(lambda x: x.squeeze() if not x.empty else None)(
    df_test.loc[df_test['Well'] == well, 'Region'])

or
res = df_test.loc[df_test['Well']==well,'Region'].squeeze()
res if len(res)>0 else None


squeeze() looks beautiful, cheers, +1!

@ThomasIsCoding squeeze is nice, but it will return an empty Series if there is no match. A more robust approach if you always want a scalar would be next+iter. You'll get the only match or first match or a default value.

Thanks, @mozway, for the observation that squeeze returns a series when there is no match. I have updated my answer to deal with such a situation.

You can use .item()
region_thiswell = df_test.loc[df_test["Well"] == well,"Region"].item()


Thanks Thomas, yes it works, but why it has to use  item()? why my code is not working?

@roudan maybe you can read through https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html# about "Indexing and selecting data"
